# Transforming image to Ascii code using conversion of grayVal to Ascii Character

Tags: java, eclipse

So basically this is the part of the program where it is supposed to convert gray value of the image to ascii codes respectively down below, but there is error saying "method must return a type of char[][]" I have succeeded for the first one ("return null") which prints blank space.

```
public static char[][] imageToASCII(Image img)
{
    BufferedImage bufImg = convert(img);
    for(int j=0; j<bufImg.getHeight(); j++)
    {
    for(int i=0; i<bufImg.getWidth(); i++)
    {

    int values=bufImg.getRGB(i,j);
    Color oldColor = new Color(values);
    int red = oldColor.getRed();        // get red value
    int green = oldColor.getGreen();    // get green value
    int blue = oldColor.getBlue();
    double grayVal = 0.299*red + 0.587*green + 0.114*blue;
    Color newColor = new Color((int)grayVal, (int)grayVal, (int)grayVal);


    if(grayVal >= 230)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if(grayVal >= 200 && grayVal < 230)
    {
        return .;
    }
    else if(grayVal >= 180 && grayVal < 200)
    {
        return *;
    }
    else if(grayVal >= 160 && grayVal < 180)
    {   
        return :;
    }
    else if(grayVal >= 130 && grayVal < 160)
    {
        return o;
    }
    else if(grayVal >= 100 && grayVal < 130)
    {
        return &;
    }
    else if(grayVal >= 70 && grayVal < 100)
    {
        return 8;
    }
    else if(grayVal >=50 && grayVal < 70)
    {
        return #;
    }
    else
        return @

    }
    }



}}
```

Comment: Well, the return type of the method is `char[][]`. That's a two-dimensional array of characters. But you write something like `return :` which is not a legal Java statement at all, and even if you used `return ':'`, that's still a single char, not a two-dimensional array of char.

Comment: Can you give me an example of return on two-dimensional array of characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to return a char you should enclose it in single-quotes. 
Second, you don't actually want to return a character, but rather set it in a matrix of characters. The following is a modification of your code which does it:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Test {
  public static char[][] imageToASCII(BufferedImage img) {
    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();
    char[][] res = new char[h][w];

    for(int j=0; j<h; j++) {
      for(int i=0; i<w; i++) {
        int values = img.getRGB(i,j);
        Color oldColor = new Color(values);
        int red = oldColor.getRed();        // get red value
        int green = oldColor.getGreen();    // get green value
        int blue = oldColor.getBlue();
        double grayVal = 0.299*red + 0.587*green + 0.114*blue;

        if(grayVal >= 230) {
          res[j][i] = ' ';
        } else if(grayVal >= 200 && grayVal < 230) {
          res[j][i] = '.';
        } else if(grayVal >= 180 && grayVal < 200) {
          res[j][i] = '*';
        } else if(grayVal >= 160 && grayVal < 180) {
          res[j][i] = ':';
        } else if(grayVal >= 130 && grayVal < 160) {
          res[j][i] = 'o';
        } else if(grayVal >= 100 && grayVal < 130) {
          res[j][i] = '&';
        } else if(grayVal >= 70 && grayVal < 100) {
          res[j][i] = '8';
        } else if(grayVal >=50 && grayVal < 70) {
          res[j][i] = '#';
        } else {
          res[j][i] = '@';
        }
      }
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

Also, this code can be quite inefficient in terms of performance. For images where W x H > 255, it's better to avoid the sequential ifs. this can be done by creating at initialization time an array which maps each possible gray value to the corresponding char, and then just dereference such array when looping through the image:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Test {
  private static char[] map;

  private static void initMap() {
    map = new char[256];
    int[][] ranges = new int[][] {
      {0, 50}, {50, 70}, {70, 100}, {100, 130},
      {130, 160}, {160, 180}, {180, 200},
      {200, 230}, {230, 256}
    };
    char[] v = {' ', '#', '8', '&', 'o', ':', '*', '.', ' '};
    for(int i=0; i<v.length; i++) {
      for(int j=ranges[i][0]; j < ranges[i][1]; j++) {
        map[j] = v[i];
      }
    }
  }

  public static char[][] imageToASCII(BufferedImage img) {
    if (map == null) {
      initMap();
    }
    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();
    char[][] res = new char[h][w];

    for(int j=0; j<h; j++) {
      for(int i=0; i<w; i++) {
        int values = img.getRGB(i,j);
        Color oldColor = new Color(values);
        int red = oldColor.getRed();        // get red value
        int green = oldColor.getGreen();    // get green value
        int blue = oldColor.getBlue();
        int grayVal = (int)(0.299*red + 0.587*green + 0.114*blue);
        if (grayVal > 255) {
          grayVal = 255;
         }
        res[j][i] = map[grayVal];
      }
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the converted ASCII image is now much bigger than the original, is there a way to quantize first into 10x10 blocks then implement it to original image? preferably using first code(the inefficient one)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a class to show you the structure of what you should return, and how to display it in console :

```
package stackOverflow;

public class ImageToGrayscale
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] image = return2DChars(30, 10);
        for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
            char[] row = image[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(row[j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static char[][] return2DChars(int width, int height) {
        char[][] image = new char[height][width];
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                image[i][j] = (Math.random() < 0.5) ? ':' : '#';
            }
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

It outputs :

```
#:#:###:::::#:#::#:::##:#::###
####:#::###:::#:###:##:::#::##
##:#:##:##:::#:##::#:###::::::
:::#:::###:#::########:#::##:#
:#::#:####:::#::#:::##::#:#:::
####::####:#:::##:##::::::####
::####:##::#:#::::#::#:#:#::#:
#::###::##:::####:::#:#:##::##
#:####::::#####:#####::###:###
::##:#:###:#:::#::####:::##:#:
```